# Calling a native C function after making a variable with that name

Tags: c++, c, variables, object, system

I have a pretty large application which holds most of the program data in a large container object called `system`.

So I access things all the time, e.g. `printf("%s\n",system.constants.jobname);`, and changing the name of `system` is undesirable.

I learned later that the function `system` exists as a native `C` function for running terminal commands, e.g. `system("rm *.txt");`

My problem is that I get compilation errors trying to use `system` as a function because it's already defined as an object.

Is there any way one can call a native `C` function explicitly ignoring programmatically defined variables? Or give the native `system` function an alias? (I'm using C++ so using it would be fine)

Comment: If you're using C++, then delete the C tag.

Comment: @Donnie a solution with C is completely welcome

Comment: In C you can't even declare a global symbol with the name `system` if you include `<stdlib.h>`. So this really is a C++ namespace issue, C can't save you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C++, `system` is in the global namespace.  Assuming you've put your stuff in a proper namespace (you have, right?) you can refer to it as `::system`.

Comment: `::system` is not guaranteed to be provided by `<cstdlib>` while `std::system` is - and the opposite for `<stdlib.h>`. If the OP is using C++, he is most probably using the first option, so `::system` is not a definite solution.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I was never formally trained so this is one of those things I never knew. I've used `std::` but not `::` by itself.

Comment: @DeiDei I'm using `stdlib.h` and `::` by itself did the trick. `std::` works too, so I'm defaulting to `std::`. Thanks.

Comment: @khaverim Do mind that using *header*.h instead of c*header* in C++ is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming using shared libraries is an acceptable solution, you can do this.

Create another C file which will not use your `system` container. Now write a function `my_system` that is a wrapper to `system`.

By wrapper I mean, it takes the same argument and calls `system` and returns what `system` returns.

Don't forget to export `my_system`

Now compile this as a dll (or .so on *NIX).

In your main project, load the dll and get a handle. Now query for address of `my_system` on the handle and make the call using function pointer.

Comment: a good concept, thank you. The other answer is more direct though.

Comment: @khaverim yes, the other answer is more direct. But I answered this for C which does not have namespaces.

Comment: Is the creation of a lib needed? I think it should also work with just making a separate .c file which does not see the variable called "system".

Comment: @Yunnosch No, that won't work because the linker would see both the symbols with same name. I believe the `system` (the function) is defined as a weak symbol and hence gets overridden by the symbol OP created. The linker would hence end up linking the call to a global variable. Unless you create a separate library, there is only 1 linker.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I tried, it works without libraray making. I think it is sufficient to make the compiler happy. The compiler will "explain" things to the linker.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya As you spotted, it worked for me because my variable "system" was local. Drawing my hat for that insight. What surprises me (after making it global), is that it compiles without complaint (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -o system.exe system.c system2.c`)  but then only has output for the printf and then nothing for the system echo, hanging. I won't ever do that, so I won't make a question. Any comment is welcome though.

Comment: So, it doesn't complain because both the files are separate translation units. Which means that they are compiled independently. So most compilers don not look for errors (or warnings) which are caused due to naming violations across modules. Now coming to why it got stuck at `system`. So both files first generate a .o file. Each of which have a symbol `system`. At assembly level there is no difference between a global and a function. They are just addresses. Now the linker has to choose 1 else because they have the same name. In general there would be a linker error saying the label is redefi

Comment: But in this case the symbol system (the function) is advertised as a weak symbol (the library does it so, so that you can reuse the name if you don't want to use the function). So the linker chooses the global variables for both. The variable and the call. It puts the address of the variable in the call instruction. Say there is no page protection, the programing ends up trying to "execute" the variable treating them as instructions. But since its just some arbitrary data and not valid instructions, the hardware rejects them and sends and exception.

Comment: In case the global data (.data section) doesn't have execute permission (which is common for most modern OSs) it throws an access violation exception and crashes. I hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: Finally for why it worked with local variables, the local variables don't create any symbols. The names are usually dissolved into offsets on the stack (for implementations that use a stack for locals). There is no reason for the compiler to put this name into the binary generated because it can't be accessed from any where else. Thus there is no name conflict and both `system` s are properly resolved.

Comment: @Yunnosch pardon the many grammatical errors. I typed on my phone and I guess autocorrect screwed it up.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thanks for the explanation. And don't worry about grammar (excuse my clichee that English won't be your native language, it isn't mine either, and I don't fool myself believing that nobody notices). I imagined more or less exactly the same things as explanation; I just did not want to believe, since I am used to compilers and linkers complaining all over the place about less problematic things... I wonder, is there something like `-Wall`for linkers.

Comment: @Yunnosch So, in linkers weak symbols is standard and hence it is not shown as a warning. Maybe if you run the linker in verbose mode it will report when a strong symbol is chosen over a weak one. The -Xlinker flag can be used to forward arguments to the linker. But the actual argument to enable verbose mode depends on your linker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144853/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-ajay-brahmakshatriya).

Comment: Just to note, I read `gcc -help=warnings` and the lack of findings supports @AjayBrahmakshatriya statement that there is sadly no (almost) standard for a linker-Wall. Seems like keywords "static inline", "weak/strong" are relevant, for anybody looking for keywords for further research. Looking forward to a suitable problem at my job, which would get me paid for studying this. ;-) Closing with a compliment to Ajay, who left a professional, patient, competent and helpful impression.

Comment: @Yunnosch I appreciate the discussion and the compliment. According to your suggestion, I will edit the answer to include the relevant parts of the discussion. :)

Comment: @Yunnosch, I found a way of locating how the linker searches for the symbols. I made two modules similar to what you had made in your answer just made the variable a global. Compiled both the c files into .o files and then tried linking them with `gcc f1.o f2.o -Xlinker -y -Xlinker _system` (32 bit windows calling convention, if you are 64 bit just write system). -y flag is to trace the symbols. It shows that _system is defined in f2.o. Then I tried `gcc f1.o -Xlinker -y -Xlinker _system` And it shows that _system is defined in C:/Program ..... / libmsvcrt.a (f2.o had the variable).

Comment: Clearly shows how the weak symbol in msvcrt.a is overridden if f2.o (the file containing the strong symbol) is included. BTW I am using mingw 32 bit on Windows.